# Traefik merge slashes

Tags: redirect, merge, docker-compose, traefik, nginx-config

I'm trying to achieve the redirect configuration of Traefik on one of the containers in the docker-compose file. I found a similar configuration called `merge_slashes` in the Nginx service configuration. This is exactly the same behavior I want to achieve.

Tried the regex alternative approach for Nginx service described here: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/relative-double-slashes-url.html

```
rewrite ^(.*)//(.*)$ $1/$2;
rewrite ^ $uri permanent;
```

But this approach not works for Traefik.

```
  labels:
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.rule: 'Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.regex: '(.*)\\/\\/+(.*)'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.replacement: '$${1}/$${2}'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.permanent: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something expected achieved by using following configurations:

```
labels:
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.rule: 'Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.regex: '(.*\\:\\/\\/.*)\\/\\/+(.*)'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.replacement: '$${1}/$${2}'
      traefik.merge_slashes.frontend.redirect.permanent: 'true'
```

But this can follows for too many redirects issue with URL like:
http://localhost/some/////////////////////////////////////////////example///url